# Insert javascript into php file (or vice versa)

Tags: javascript, php, client, server

I have a Server file written in php, and a client html file (mainly javascript), I want to have both put into one file and still communicate. I tried copying the php code of the server above the client code but it didn't work. So this is how it was like:

```
  <!doctype html>
<html>




    <meta charset='UTF-8' />
    <style>
        input, textarea {border:1px solid #CCC;margin:0px;padding:0px}
        #body {max-width:800px;margin:auto}
        #log {width:100%;height:400px}
        #message {width:100%;line-height:20px}
    </style>


    <?php

// prevent the server from timing out

set_time_limit(0);



// include the web sockets server script (the server is started at the far bottom of this file)

require 'class.PHPWebSocket.php';



// when a client sends data to the server

function wsOnMessage($clientID, $message, $messageLength, $binary) {

    global $Server;

    $ip = long2ip( $Server->wsClients[$clientID][6] );



    // check if message length is 0

    if ($messageLength == 0) {

        $Server->wsClose($clientID);

        return;

    }

$x = 0;

    //The speaker is the only person in the room. Don't let them feel lonely.



for ($i=1; $i <= 10; $i++) {



$q=".68.111.160";

$string =100+$i*10;

$string .= $q;

$Server->wsSend($clientID, $string);



    sleep (3);

}





}



// when a client connects

function wsOnOpen($clientID)

{

    global $Server;

    $ip = long2ip( $Server->wsClients[$clientID][6] );



    $Server->log( "$ip ($clientID) has connected." );



    //Send a join notice to everyone but the person who joined

    foreach ( $Server->wsClients as $id => $client )

        if ( $id != $clientID )

            $Server->wsSend($id, "Visitor $clientID ($ip) has joined the room.");

}



// when a client closes or lost connection

function wsOnClose($clientID, $status) {

    global $Server;

    $ip = long2ip( $Server->wsClients[$clientID][6] );



    $Server->log( "$ip ($clientID) has disconnected." );



    //Send a user left notice to everyone in the room

    foreach ( $Server->wsClients as $id => $client )

        $Server->wsSend($id, "Visitor $clientID ($ip) has left the room.");

}



// start the server

$Server = new PHPWebSocket();

$Server->bind('message', 'wsOnMessage');

$Server->bind('open', 'wsOnOpen');

$Server->bind('close', 'wsOnClose');

// for other computers to connect, you will probably need to change this to your LAN IP or external IP,

// alternatively use: gethostbyaddr(gethostbyname($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']))

$Server->wsStartServer('127.0.0.1', 9300);



?>


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="fancywebsocket.js"></script>
    <script>
        var Server;
        function log( text ) {
            $log = $('#log');
            //Add text to log
            $log.append(($log.val()?"\n":'')+text);
            //Autoscroll
            $log[0].scrollTop = $log[0].scrollHeight - $log[0].clientHeight;
        }
        function send( text ) {
            Server.send( 'message', text );
        }
    </script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://datamaps.github.io/scripts/datamaps.world.min.js?v=1"></script>
    <script src="converter.js"></script>
    <div id="container1" style="position: relative; width:900px; height: 700px;"></div>
    <script>
        var map = new Datamap({
            scope: 'world',
            element: document.getElementById('container1'),
            projection: 'mercator',
            fills: {
                lt50: 'rgba(0,244,244,0.9)',
                on: 'red',
                HIGH: '#afafaf',
                LOW: '#123456',
                MEDIUM: 'blue',
                UNKNOWN: 'rgb(50,0,0)',
                off: "#ABDDA4",
                defaultFill: "#ABDDA4"
            },
            data: {
            }
        })
        var x;
        var colors = d3.scale.category10();
        $(document).ready(function() {
            log('Connecting...');
            Server = new FancyWebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:9300');
            $('#message').keypress(function(e) {
                if ( e.keyCode == 13 && this.value ) {
                    log( 'You: ' + this.value );
                    send( this.value );
                    $(this).val('');
                }
            });
            //Let the user know we're connected
            Server.bind('open', function() {
                log( "Connected." );
            });
            //OH NOES! Disconnection occurred.
            Server.bind('close', function( data ) {
                log( "Disconnected." );
            });
            //Log any messages sent from server
            Server.bind('message', function( payload ) {
log( payload );
                  var ip = payload;
        $.get("http://ipinfo.io/" + ip, function(response) {
            x = response.country;
        }, "jsonp");
        var interval_x = window.setInterval(function() {
            var country_name = convert[x];
            var interval_1 = window.setInterval(function() {
                var country = {}
                var country = {}
                country[country_name] = {
                    fillKey: 'on'
                }
                map.updateChoropleth(country);
            }, 2000);
            myVar = window.setTimeout(function() {
                clearInterval(interval_1);
                var country = {}
                country[country_name] = {
                    fillKey: 'off'
                }
                map.updateChoropleth(country);
            }, 4000);
        }, 4000);
            });
            Server.connect();
        });
//---------------------------------------IP  Goes Here------------------------------------------------
    </script>
<body>
    <div id='body'>
        <textarea id='log' name='log' readonly='readonly'></textarea><br/>
        <input type='text' id='message' name='message' />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

But it wouldn't work, knowing that this was put in an html file.

Comment: PHP doesn't execute in html files.

Comment: @Daan so what should i do ?

Comment: If you want the php to execute change .html to .php. Note that php needs to be installed on your server.

Answer (score 0):

We don't have all your embedded scripts for this special case. But generally you can put HTML, CSS, PHP and JavaScript in the same file. The file has to end with '.php' and PHP must be installed ("test.php"):

```
<!doctype html>
<html><head>

    <title>Test</title>

</head><body>

    <div id="test">
        <?php echo 'foobar'; ?>
    </div>

    <script>
        alert(document.getElementById('test').innerHTML);
    </script>

</body></html>
```

Should output "foobar".

Comment: So the whole code should be put in a php file right ? if so, how do u run a php file by a browser ?

Comment: Just navigate to the file in the address bar: http://localhost/test.php for example

Comment: Thank you, i have done that, but it just displays the php code in a dialogue box then i press ok it just shows the client side (javascript)

Comment: Then you do not have correctly PHP installed on your local web server. Follow instructions on http://www.php.net

Comment: I've ran your code and it works, then i did the same for my code and i received this error 

http://localhost/test.php [HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error 6ms]

Comment: And the screen is just blank.

Comment: Take a look at the error log, to see what's going wrong